# Is there a plugin which allows me to save additional, invisible content per post?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, attachments

For a blog project, I need to be able to attach content to each blog post which isn't visible to the casual reader but to all editors.

Think of it as a collection of reference materials, comments and ideas which I'd like to keep. If possible, then I'd like to see this section along with the normal blog editor (so I can edit both at the same time).

Note that I'd like to create a multilingual blog, but it would be alright if this additional information would show up only in the main language (English) instead of being translated. But it should show up in all language versions.

Answer (score 5):

I like [this idea from wprecipes.com](http://www.wprecipes.com/add-private-notes-to-your-wordpress-blog-posts). It is a very lightweight solution.

```
add_shortcode( 'note', 'sc_note' );

function sc_note( $atts, $content = null ) {
     if ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
        return '<div class="note">'.$content.'</div>';
    return '';
}
```

It allows you to use the `[note]...[/note]` shortcode to enter private comments.

Comment: +1 nice idea. I'd prefer a extra, stand alone field, though.